# Create a adapter without knowing the driver type

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataadapter

One of the great things with ADO.net is that you dont have to know which kind of connections/commands that you are using (interface based programming). You can use a connection to create a command, and command to create a reader.

```
IDbConnectin con = CreateConnection(_connectionString); //factory method
IDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

But how do I create a IDataAdapter in the same way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Public Overridable Function CreateDataAdapter() As System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter
     Member of System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory
Summary:
Returns a new instance of the provider's class that implements the System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter class.

Return Values:
A new instance of System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.
```

I have done what you are asking, but I cannot find the code. I will update answer when I can.

Comment: No need to update. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Found a article here about the whole concept: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9f29wbk(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: @jgauffin: Yes, that was one of the links I tried to find earlier. I was able to create a data-access-layer that worked against SqlCe, OleDb, and SqlClient. All I had to do was pass an enumeration for the provider I wanted. Connection string read from .config. It worked perfectly.